# RSS Feed: Post is written in Feed, if comment count on post is 5,10,15,20

Tags: php, rss, wordpress

I have a wordpress site and use RSS Graffiti on Facebook to share my newest posts there.

Now i´m wondering: I want to build an RSS Feed, where the post appears as entry as soon as it has reached a certain comment count, say 5,10,20,etc.
This way i can share the post on facebook as "active".

Now I´m thinking of how to do it and how to do it best.

Solutions i came up with:

1) PHP-code, that counts the number of comments and if count is 10, 15, 20,... adds category "c10" to post. I then take the built in wordpress-feed for categories to share it on fb.

Problem: I will need a lot of categories and spam my background

2) I have a plugin, that counts the number of comments and then generates an rss feed of its own. 
Would be much cleaner, but i dont know how to do this, make an RSS Feed of my own and program the post in there.

Is there another solution? What do you think?

Comment: nobody? there has to be an easy solution here.